# Docking buttons in the wpf panels

Tags: c#, wpf, panel, anchor, docking

How can it be done? If there are, for example, four groups of buttons in menu-like panel. How would you dock them to their initial location if the window is resized?

I am trying this using DockPanel and HorizontalAlign, but it seems to only be work for the last button on the right when the window is resized. But how do you dock(anchor) a group of buttons? Maybe put them in border object and use HorizontalAlign for it? Is there more elegant way to do this?

Comment: can't you just put the grouped buttons in a StackPanel or Gird?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to create WPF apps in the old windforms way. WPF pretty much does all the layout for you. Just use Grids and StackPanels as stijn suggests

Comment: Read this article about the WPF Panels and pick the one that does the right job for you, or nest panels to get the desired result:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx

Comment: I have add <Border> that contains stackpanel with this buttons - it solved my problem but it is not beutifull way

Comment: why is that not beautiful? it's the shortest ath to the solution: you want grouped buttons, so you have to tell wpf about your intent to group them. You put them in a stackpanel and now they are grouped. I don't know how one could make it more beautifull like that?

Comment: What do you mean with "not beatiful"? If you need more space between the elements add a margin to the buttons.

Comment: @stijn: Post your comment as an answer. I'll up vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments: I don't know your background but it seems you are used to another way of UI design where you do not explicitely have to specify grouping etc in code. While that might seem more elegant, it is not: the designer generated code is awful and the whole system is not as flexible nor srtaightforward as what WPF gives you..

With WPF you get a clear one-to-one relationship between your intent (*treating buttons as a group within a layout*) and the actual code (*put the buttons in a stackpanel/grid/...*). Or *draw a border around buttons and organize them vertically within the border* vs in xaml *use a border with a stackpanel inside*. It won't get any more elegant than that.

Read up on WPF layouts and once you'll get a grip of it you will quickly see that it is rather powerful and beatiful at the same time. I found [this tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Layout.html) pretty helpful when just starting with layouts. And google provides lots and lots and lots more information, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Like stijn said, put the buttons in a Grid or a Stackpanel and you'll be fine.
You may not think it's beautifull, but it's the best solution for your problem.